# Ethernet interface on Debian has two ipv4 addresses

Tags: debian, network-interface

I added a static IP configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.ifcfg` which works on that subnet, but for some reason there is a second ipv4 address on `eth0` that is consuming routes to any other network (and blocking my shared internet).

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.20.30.3/24 brd 10.20.30.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.174.16/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ee45:55ba:b560:a416/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr e4:5f:01:73:89:6e
```

The address `169.254.174.16` is the one I don't want. How can I figure out where it's coming from, and how to remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question: it's a conflict with `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, where an `arping` address `A.B.C.D` had already been configured for that interface, but `A.B.C.D` was no longer available on the network. Instead of ignoring the unreachable address, `dhcpcd` falls back to standard DHCP, without checking if another (reachable) address has already been assigned elsewhere. So the interface was getting DHCP from `dhcpcd.conf` and in parallel `E.F.G.H` from `/etc/networks/interfaces.d/eth0.ifcfg`. The solution is just to remove `eth0.ifcfg` and change the `arping` address in `dhcpcd.conf` to `E.F.G.H`.